# How can I know that Yii2 has linked a specific bootstrap jquery plugin in my application?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am developping an application using bootstrap; the problem is the dropdown of bootstrap is not working well so I wound if it loaded in my application.

So how can I know a specific bootstrap plugin is there or how can I tell yii that I want to use this plugin of bootstrap?

Here is the simplest thing I tried:

My Html:

```
<a id="anotherbut">Laumch</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a id="but" data-toggle="dropdown">Drop it down</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Bonjour</li>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>Hi Mr</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My Javascript :

```
$("body").on("click","#anotherbut",function(){
        $("#but").dropdown("toggle");
        });
```

But it doesn't work.  I can even see the code reacting but instead of changing on the #but element

> aria-expended="false"

to

> aria-expended="true"

```
 it still keeping false and on the div(wrapper) the class
```

> open

;

Answer (score 1):

Yii's Asset Bundles represent groups of JavaScript and CSS files that need to be included together on specific pages or across the site and An asset bundle class should be autoloadable.
 e.g :
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

```
class BackendAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $css = [
        'your_specific_css.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
        'your_specific_js.js',

    ];

    public $depends = [ 
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
}
```

after above code, load in layout.

```
AppAsset::register($this);
```

you can read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html)

Comment: 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset', is there in my AssetBundle but 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' ; I was told that is enough but even adding does nothing @asusi